# prioritized experience replay in deep Q-learning

Tags: deep-learning, priority-queue, reinforcement-learning, q-learning

i was implementing DQN in [mountain car problem](https://gym.openai.com/envs/MountainCar-v0) of openai gym. this problem is special as the positive reward is very sparse. so i thought of implementing prioritized experience replay as proposed in this [paper by google deep mind](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.05952.pdf).

there are certain things that are confusing me:

- how do we store the replay memory. i get that p<sub>i</sub> is the priority of transition and there are two ways but what is this P(i)?
- if we follow the rules given won't P(i) change every time a sample is added.
- what does it mean when it says "we sample according to this probability distribution". what is the distribution.
- finally how do we sample from it. i get that if we store it in a priority queue we can sample directly but we are actually storing it in a sum tree.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- According to the paper, there are two ways for calculating Pi and base on your choice, your implementation differs. I assume you selected Proportional Prioriziation then you should use "sum-tree" data structure for storing a pair of transition and P(i). P(i) is just the normalized version of Pi and it shows how important that transition is or in other words how effective that transition is for improving your network. When P(i) is high, it means it's so surprising for the network so it can really help the network to tune itself.
- You should add each new transition with infinity priority to make sure it will be played at least once and there is no need to update all the experience replay memory for each new coming transition. During the experience replay process, you select a mini-batch and update the probability of those experiences in the mini-batch.
- Each experience has a probability so all of the experiences together make a distribution and we select our next mini-batch according to this distribution.
- You can sample via this policy from your sum-tree:

```py
def retrieve(n, s):
    if n is leaf_node: return n
    if n.left.val >= s: return retrieve(n.left, s)
    else: return retrieve(n.right, s - n.left.val)
```

I have taken the code from [here](https://jaromiru.com/2016/11/07/lets-make-a-dqn-double-learning-and-prioritized-experience-replay/).

Comment: still not getting it. won't batch size change depending on s. also would't a priority queue be a better idea to use

Comment: we call retrieve function for each sample. I mean if you have a mini-batch which size is 32 then you should call the function 32 times. Heap isn't suitable because that gives you the most probability in each step and there is no chance for other experiences to be selected but using sum-tree all experiences have the chance to be selected and they also can be updated efficiently.

Comment: thanks. i successful understood and implemented it. just one last thing, do we use sum tree to just introduce a little randomness otherwise i am not able to see how it is better the priority queue

Comment: The main usage of Heap is for selecting a maximum or minimum among some values. In this field, we want to select some numbers randomly according to their probability. We don't want to select experience which has the highest probability, so heap is not that much helpful.

Comment: @SajadNorouzi when you said "infinity priority" do you mean just a very large number? Does it matter the size of that number?

Comment: Yes, just a very large number. Basically a number which is higher than all the other numbers in the tree. You can use something like math.inf.

Answer (score 1):

You can reuse the code in [OpenAI Baseline](https://github.com/openai/baselines/blob/master/baselines/deepq/replay_buffer.py) or using [SumTree](https://github.com/rlcode/per/blob/master/SumTree.py)

```py
import numpy as np
import random

from baselines.common.segment_tree import SumSegmentTree, MinSegmentTree


class ReplayBuffer(object):
    def __init__(self, size):
        """Create Replay buffer.
        Parameters
        ----------
        size: int
            Max number of transitions to store in the buffer. When the buffer
            overflows the old memories are dropped.
        """
        self._storage = []
        self._maxsize = size
        self._next_idx = 0

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._storage)

    def add(self, obs_t, action, reward, obs_tp1, done):
        data = (obs_t, action, reward, obs_tp1, done)

        if self._next_idx >= len(self._storage):
            self._storage.append(data)
        else:
            self._storage[self._next_idx] = data
        self._next_idx = (self._next_idx + 1) % self._maxsize

    def _encode_sample(self, idxes):
        obses_t, actions, rewards, obses_tp1, dones = [], [], [], [], []
        for i in idxes:
            data = self._storage[i]
            obs_t, action, reward, obs_tp1, done = data
            obses_t.append(np.array(obs_t, copy=False))
            actions.append(np.array(action, copy=False))
            rewards.append(reward)
            obses_tp1.append(np.array(obs_tp1, copy=False))
            dones.append(done)
        return np.array(obses_t), np.array(actions), np.array(rewards), np.array(obses_tp1), np.array(dones)

    def sample(self, batch_size):
        """Sample a batch of experiences.
        Parameters
        ----------
        batch_size: int
            How many transitions to sample.
        Returns
        -------
        obs_batch: np.array
            batch of observations
        act_batch: np.array
            batch of actions executed given obs_batch
        rew_batch: np.array
            rewards received as results of executing act_batch
        next_obs_batch: np.array
            next set of observations seen after executing act_batch
        done_mask: np.array
            done_mask[i] = 1 if executing act_batch[i] resulted in
            the end of an episode and 0 otherwise.
        """
        idxes = [random.randint(0, len(self._storage) - 1) for _ in range(batch_size)]
        return self._encode_sample(idxes)


class PrioritizedReplayBuffer(ReplayBuffer):
    def __init__(self, size, alpha):
        """Create Prioritized Replay buffer.
        Parameters
        ----------
        size: int
            Max number of transitions to store in the buffer. When the buffer
            overflows the old memories are dropped.
        alpha: float
            how much prioritization is used
            (0 - no prioritization, 1 - full prioritization)
        See Also
        --------
        ReplayBuffer.__init__
        """
        super(PrioritizedReplayBuffer, self).__init__(size)
        assert alpha >= 0
        self._alpha = alpha

        it_capacity = 1
        while it_capacity < size:
            it_capacity *= 2

        self._it_sum = SumSegmentTree(it_capacity)
        self._it_min = MinSegmentTree(it_capacity)
        self._max_priority = 1.0

    def add(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """See ReplayBuffer.store_effect"""
        idx = self._next_idx
        super().add(*args, **kwargs)
        self._it_sum[idx] = self._max_priority ** self._alpha
        self._it_min[idx] = self._max_priority ** self._alpha

    def _sample_proportional(self, batch_size):
        res = []
        p_total = self._it_sum.sum(0, len(self._storage) - 1)
        every_range_len = p_total / batch_size
        for i in range(batch_size):
            mass = random.random() * every_range_len + i * every_range_len
            idx = self._it_sum.find_prefixsum_idx(mass)
            res.append(idx)
        return res

    def sample(self, batch_size, beta):
        """Sample a batch of experiences.
        compared to ReplayBuffer.sample
        it also returns importance weights and idxes
        of sampled experiences.
        Parameters
        ----------
        batch_size: int
            How many transitions to sample.
        beta: float
            To what degree to use importance weights
            (0 - no corrections, 1 - full correction)
        Returns
        -------
        obs_batch: np.array
            batch of observations
        act_batch: np.array
            batch of actions executed given obs_batch
        rew_batch: np.array
            rewards received as results of executing act_batch
        next_obs_batch: np.array
            next set of observations seen after executing act_batch
        done_mask: np.array
            done_mask[i] = 1 if executing act_batch[i] resulted in
            the end of an episode and 0 otherwise.
        weights: np.array
            Array of shape (batch_size,) and dtype np.float32
            denoting importance weight of each sampled transition
        idxes: np.array
            Array of shape (batch_size,) and dtype np.int32
            idexes in buffer of sampled experiences
        """
        assert beta > 0

        idxes = self._sample_proportional(batch_size)

        weights = []
        p_min = self._it_min.min() / self._it_sum.sum()
        max_weight = (p_min * len(self._storage)) ** (-beta)

        for idx in idxes:
            p_sample = self._it_sum[idx] / self._it_sum.sum()
            weight = (p_sample * len(self._storage)) ** (-beta)
            weights.append(weight / max_weight)
        weights = np.array(weights)
        encoded_sample = self._encode_sample(idxes)
        return tuple(list(encoded_sample) + [weights, idxes])

    def update_priorities(self, idxes, priorities):
        """Update priorities of sampled transitions.
        sets priority of transition at index idxes[i] in buffer
        to priorities[i].
        Parameters
        ----------
        idxes: [int]
            List of idxes of sampled transitions
        priorities: [float]
            List of updated priorities corresponding to
            transitions at the sampled idxes denoted by
            variable `idxes`.
        """
        assert len(idxes) == len(priorities)
        for idx, priority in zip(idxes, priorities):
            assert priority > 0
            assert 0 <= idx < len(self._storage)
            self._it_sum[idx] = priority ** self._alpha
            self._it_min[idx] = priority ** self._alpha

            self._max_priority = max(self._max_priority, priority)
```